# Maven deploy to relative directory path

Tags: maven

I can deploy to an absolute directory:

```
<distributionManagement>
    <repository>
        <id>absolute directory</id>
        <url>file:///home/tukushan/workspace/omcutil/repo</url>
    </repository>
</distributionManagement>
```

But how do I deploy to a directory relative to my project's directory?

Comment: The question is why would you like to do?

Comment: I have a repo directory of binaries in my source repository which gets pushed to googlecode and becomes the public maven repository for the project. I'm not sure if there's any other way to host a public maven repository on googlecode?

Comment: Did things change? I didn't use maven 3 yrs ago but I feel like constructs akin to that of OP with `file:${basedir}/...` work fine these days.

Comment: I tried with relative path and it worked :/ (using maven 3.6.0). Actually I tried using absolute path first but got an error saying it didn't find the given relative path

Answer (score 20, accepted):

A relative directory can be specified when using the `-DaltDeploymentRepository` parameter, e.g.:

```
mvn deploy -DaltDeploymentRepository=snapshot-repo::default::file:../../my-local-snapshots-dir
```

The file URL is relative to the directory in which `mvn` is run.

See [here](http://cemerick.com/2010/08/24/hosting-maven-repos-on-github) for more info on the `altDeploymentRepository` parameter.

Comment: Doesn't work for me, I get: `ArtifactDeployerException: Failed to retrieve remote metadata [my-group]:[my-artifact]:1.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml: Could not transfer metadata [my-group]:[my-artifact]:1.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from/to snapshot-repo::default (file:../nexus_test/snapshots): [my .m2 path]\repository\[install-jar-folder]\1.0-SNAPSHOT\maven-metadata-snapshot-repo::default.xml.part.lock (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect) -> [Help 1]`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it can be done. File URLs require a mount point on the server, for example:

```
file://hostname/path/to/file
```

So, for a file on the local filesystem simply omits the "hostname" component (Explaining the 3 leading slashes):

```
file:///path/to/file
```

A relative path on the other hand assumes a starting position in the remote filesystem... Something that is impossible to support if one wants a URL to be unambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very old thread, but so are the answers.

@tekumara's answer works fine, but only for maven version <= 2

this works for 3+

```
mvn deploy -DaltDeploymentRepository=local::file:./target/staging-deploy
```

ref: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/examples/deploy-network-issues.html#deploying-to-a-local-directory

note - this also explains and solves the "ArtifactDeployerException: Failed to retrieve remote metadata.."  error mentioned below.